# Install Entity Framewok v5 in Webmatrix 2 RC

Tags: nuget, webmatrix

I'm working on a project with Entity Framework in Webmatrix 2 RC, so I need to use Entity Framework v.5 RC because of conflicts between previous versions and .NET Framework 4.5.

The two ways I know to install NuGet packages in Webmatrix are from the NuGet Gallery on the Webmatrix ribbon and from the package manager in ASP.NET Web Pages Administration: either solution proposes only Entity Framework v4.3.1.

I have downloaded Entity Framework v.5 RC with the Package Manager Console of Visual Web Developer and copied the EntityFramework.dll into the bin folder of my project.

This solution works but I wonder if exists a way to install a not recommended NuGet package that doesn't require the use of Visual Web Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nuget.exe](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939) or [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/), both are standalone and lightweight. You'll still have to manually add references to the files though.